# Customizing task support for Scala parallel collections?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Suppose that I create an new `ParMap` with a custom task support object as described in the [Scala documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html).

```
val existingOrders = parallel.mutable.ParMap.empty[UUID, Order]
existingOrders.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(...)
```

After adding a bunch of orders to the `existingOrders` I now want to apply a filter `p` to the values of this collection to extract a subset as follows. Simplest way to do this would be the following.

```
val filteredOrders = existingOrders.values.filter(p)
```

Now the type of `existingOrders.values` is `ParIterable[Order]`. I would like to know from where does `existingOrders.values` get its task support object that controls scheduling and load balancing for the filtering operation? Does is use the custom task support object that I created for `existingOrders`? Does it use the default task support object?

Another possible implementation would be to perform the filtering operation first and then return the values:

```
val filteredOrders = existingOrders.filter { case (_, order) => p(order) }
filteredOrders.values
```

This would clearly use the custom task support object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does is use the custom task support object that I created for
>   existingOrders? Does it use the default task support object?

No, it doesn't flow your custom `tasksupport` object to the `ParIterable[Order]`, [it uses the default `ExecutionContextTaskSupport` as mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html). You can see this when printing out the `existingOrders.values.tasksupport`:

```
import scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool

scala> val parMap = Map(1 -> 1).par
parMap: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParMap[Int,Int] = ParMap(1 -> 1)

scala> val taskSupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(1))
taskSupport: scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport = scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport@26fadd98

scala> parMap.tasksupport = taskSupport
parMap.tasksupport: scala.collection.parallel.TaskSupport = scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport@26fadd98

scala> parMap.values.tasksupport
res1: scala.collection.parallel.TaskSupport = scala.collection.parallel.ExecutionContextTaskSupport@2991524
```

Comment: Wow, is this at all intuitive? That makes `parCollection.filter.map....` sequences only use the configured task support for the first step. Maybe it's speced like that but doesn't seem to match mine and other folks expectations.

Comment: @mernst Oh this is definitely not intuitive. I wouldn't use native Scala for parallelism. I'd use something like [`ZIO`](https://zio.dev/)